# how to solve org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40d310f0)

Tags: android, jax-ws, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

i have create simple webservice using jax-ws. i need to consume that webservice in android.
when i consume that webservice i got this error
 **`org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40d310f0)`**

my wsdl code:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://sample.jaxws.ws.blog.accrd.com/" name="SimpleWebServiceService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://sample.jaxws.ws.blog.accrd.com/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/SimpleWebService/SimpleWebService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="sayHello"><part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHello"/></message><message name="sayHelloResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="SimpleWebService"><operation name="sayHello">
<input wsam:Action="http://sample.jaxws.ws.blog.accrd.com/SimpleWebService/sayHelloRequest" message="tns:sayHello"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://sample.jaxws.ws.blog.accrd.com/SimpleWebService/sayHelloResponse" message="tns:sayHelloResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="SimpleWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:SimpleWebService">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/><operation name="sayHello">
<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="SimpleWebServiceService">
<port name="SimpleWebServicePort" binding="tns:SimpleWebServicePortBinding"><soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/SimpleWebService/SimpleWebService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


  public final static String URL ="http://localhost:8080/SimpleWebService/SimpleWebService?wsdl"; 
  public  static final String NAMESPACE = "http://sample.jaxws.ws.blog.accrd.com/";
  public static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sample.jaxws.ws.blog.accrd.com/sayHello"; 
  private static final   String METHOD = "sayHello";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
            Customer cu = new Customer();

            cu.setFirstName("FirstName");
            cu.setLastName("LastName");
            PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo();
            propInfo.name = "arg0";
            propInfo.type = Customer.class;
            request.addProperty(propInfo, cu);




            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER12);




            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                Log.d("Error", "Finished");

                SoapObject response=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;



                tv.setText(response.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error", e.toString());

            }

        }
    });

}}
```

My Customer.java

```
    public class Customer implements KvmSerializable {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
        Object object = null;
        switch (arg0) {

        case 0:
            object = this.firstName;
            break;
        case 1:
            object = this.lastName;
            break;

        }
        return object;

    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1,
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            propertyInfo.name = "firstName";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;

        case 1:
            propertyInfo.name = "lastName";
            propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int arg0, Object object) {
        switch (arg0) {

        case 0:
            this.firstName = object.toString();
            break;

        case 1:
            this.lastName = object.toString();
            break;

        }

    }

}
```

when i use @BindingType is soap1.1 in my jax-ws webservice i get correct response. but when i use @BindingType is soap1.2 in my jax-ws webservice i get this error **org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40d310f0).**

How can solve this Problem?

Comment: please debug and find what line this error is produced, also in the future it's a good idea to use a library like RoboSpice to handle network operations for you, a lot easier :)

Comment: the error line is androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error means that the response you are getting is empty or doesn't fit your envelope, can you confirm that?

Comment: yes. that's not fit my envelope.

Comment: Ok so isn't the error justified? Isn't it a problem with your webservice? Also in general SOAP is kinda dead and REST has a lot better support on Android

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34004/discussion-between-jeevamuthu-and-rsenapps)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After talking to @jeevamuthu, the problem was he had to add the ksoap library to his build path, and make minor adjustments to his code. If you are having a similar issue please contact @jeevamuthu for information in solving this problem.

```
PropertyInfo propInfo = new PropertyInfo(); 
propInfo.name = "arg0"; propInfo.value=cu; 
propInfo.type = Customer.class; 
request.addProperty(propInfo);
```