# KSoap2-Android XMLPullParserException - SOAP web service client on Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

please I have problem with **sending XML through kSoap**. I want to send some personal data in XML format through SOAP. I am getting this error:

```
03-03 11:01:07.464: W/System.err(7366): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@412a6410) 
03-03 11:01:07.464: W/System.err(7366):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2035)
03-03 11:01:07.464: W/System.err(7366):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
03-03 11:01:07.464: W/System.err(7366):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
03-03 11:01:07.464: W/System.err(7366):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
03-03 11:01:07.464: W/System.err(7366):     at dp.fedorko.client.soapClient.Upload2(soapClient.java:79)
03-03 11:01:07.464: W/System.err(7366):     at dp.fedorko.client.soapClient.doInBackground(soapClient.java:181)
03-03 11:01:07.474: W/System.err(7366):     at dp.fedorko.client.soapClient.doInBackground(soapClient.java:1)*
...
```

Here is my code

```
public String Upload2(String xml) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1); 
        PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi1.setName("Xml");
        pi1.setValue(xml);
        pi1.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi1);
        Log.i("TAG", "XML: " + xml);    
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        Log.i("TAG", "Envelope: " + envelope.toString());       
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String s = response.toString();
            return s;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
     }
```

And this is my xml, which I want to send (as parameter of soap operation):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><Upload><Person><Name value="mobile6" /><Active value="1" /><Datas><Data>25:255:1:0:1:1:0:0:3:1:0:2:1:5:0:0:0:8:0:0:1:0:3:0:4:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0</Data></Datas></Person></Upload>
```

Please can anyone advice, where can be a problem?

also here is generated wsdl on server side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="urn:recognitionwsdl" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" targetNamespace="urn:recognitionwsdl">
   <types>
      <xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:recognitionwsdl">
         <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
      </xsd:schema>
   </types>
   <message name="uploadAndTestRequest">
      <part name="xmlfile" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>
   <message name="uploadAndTestResponse">
      <part name="return" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>
   <message name="udfRecognitionTestRequest">
      <part name="xmlfile" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>
   <message name="udfRecognitionTestResponse">
      <part name="return" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>
   <message name="udfRecognitionTest2Request">
      <part name="xmlfile" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>
   <message name="udfRecognitionTest2Response">
      <part name="return" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>
   <message name="webServiceTestRequest" />
   <message name="webServiceTestResponse">
      <part name="return" type="xsd:string" />
   </message>
   <portType name="recognitionwsdlPortType">
      <operation name="uploadAndTest">
         <documentation>Upload new person and train vectors</documentation>
         <input message="tns:uploadAndTestRequest" />
         <output message="tns:uploadAndTestResponse" />
      </operation>
      <operation name="udfRecognitionTest">
         <documentation>Test for peson with udf</documentation>
         <input message="tns:udfRecognitionTestRequest" />
         <output message="tns:udfRecognitionTestResponse" />
      </operation>
      <operation name="udfRecognitionTest2">
         <documentation>Test for peson with udf</documentation>
         <input message="tns:udfRecognitionTest2Request" />
         <output message="tns:udfRecognitionTest2Response" />
      </operation>
      <operation name="webServiceTest">
         <documentation>Test web service</documentation>
         <input message="tns:webServiceTestRequest" />
         <output message="tns:webServiceTestResponse" />
      </operation>
   </portType>
   <binding name="recognitionwsdlBinding" type="tns:recognitionwsdlPortType">
      <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
      <operation name="uploadAndTest">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:recognitionwsdl#connectAndTest" style="rpc" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:recognitionwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:recognitionwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="udfRecognitionTest">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:recognitionwsdl#udfRecognitionTest" style="rpc" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:recognitionwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:recognitionwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="udfRecognitionTest2">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:recognitionwsdl#udfRecognitionTest2" style="rpc" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:recognitionwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:recognitionwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
      <operation name="webServiceTest">
         <soap:operation soapAction="urn:recognitionwsdl#webServiceTest" style="rpc" />
         <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:recognitionwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:recognitionwsdl" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>
   <service name="recognitionwsdl">
      <port name="recognitionwsdlPort" binding="tns:recognitionwsdlBinding">
         <soap:address location="http://[address]/server.php" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

Here is code that runs everything together:

```
public String uploadFaceToServer(String name, String LBP){
            xmlParser xparser = new xmlParser();
            soapClient client = new soapClient();
            String xml = xparser.writeUploadXml(name, "25:255:1:0:1:1:0:0:3:1:0:2:1:5:0:0:0:8:0:0:1:0:3:0:4:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0");

            try {
                        return client.execute(1, xml).get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return "Chyba";
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return "Chyba";
                }

        }
```

Please I am getting stuck on this error few weeks. I need some support. Please help!

Thank you

Martin Fedorko
Slovak Technical University

Comment: hi have you added  ksoap library in yours build path properly!! also visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816871/how-to-solve-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-unexpected-type-positionen

Comment: Hi, it seems to be fine, because when I call simplier function from my web service (that has no parameter and returns just text "Webservice is reachable" ) , this works fine in my android application.

Comment: oh ok, than again i will try to check and will be back if i will have a better and valid answer!!

Comment: It would be perfect, because I am stuck on this two weeks and I cannot find any solution. I can upload hole source code if you need.

Comment: here is my full code: http://www.sendspace.com/file/e35ldq

Comment: client code that runs SoapClient and create XML: http://pastebin.com/FYMgJ2aH

Comment: Please can you look at it again? Because I must get though it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It was error on server side. I have bad php mysql settings and some other errors

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in so many examples for passing parameters to a c# web service from android:
    PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
    pi1.setName("Xml");
    pi1.setValue(xml);
    pi1.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi1);

I guess this is how older versions of ksoap worked? Any ways I was in you situation a few weeks ago. For days it made me think I buggered up my c# web service which was not correct. I was passing my parameters the same way you are and I later found out that was the error!

This is how to pass parameters properly from Ksoap in Android to a c# web service:
    request.addProperty("name of parameter in method in c# webservice", xml);

Comment: I tried to put request.addProperty("xmlfile", xml); But this didn't help.

Comment: and my client is not written in c#, but java, it is android client

Comment: Weird that should of worked. I have mine set up like that and its working beautifully. Could you please post the method you want to call from your web service?

Comment: I want to call UploadAndTest method

Comment: Well your passing through the values for the parameters fine. I' ve gone through your code again and the only difference I see is that I'm using : SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
And your using SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
Try changing it to VER11

Comment: What version of KSoap are you running? Mines 2.4

Comment: My assembly is named ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar , so probably the same :)

Comment: Your Android code looks fine and should be able to call the service from your php web service. The only thing I can think of at this point is that there is an issue with the web service method.

Comment: hm, but this method works fine with C# client . Cannot be problem with some name of method or url adress or somethink like that? Is there any way to analyze it?

Comment: Ah possibly. What is the text for NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1, SOAP_ACTION1?

Comment: private static final String SOAP_ACTION1 = "urn:recognitionwsdl/connectAndTest";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME1 = "uploadAndTest";
    private static String URL = "http://[ip]/webservicerecognition/server.php?wsdl";